# Adding labels to a specific group in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, label, geom-text

I would like to add labels for a specific group (birds) in a scatterplot with several groups.

I tried the several suggestions in [How to do selective labeling with GGPLOT geom_point()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015356/how-to-do-selective-labeling-with-ggplot-geom-point) but no success. The code below gets the labels but for all groups and looks really noisy. Since there are error bars I probably should move the labels up and over to avoid the error bars.

Thanks,

Jeff

```
  x = d13C_mean,
  y = d15N_mean,
  color=Class, shape=Class)) + 
  geom_point(stroke=2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = d15N_mean - d15N_sd, ymax = d15N_mean + d15N_sd)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = d13C_mean - d13C_sd, xmax = d13C_mean + d13C_sd))
p + ggtitle("Nescopeck Warm Season") +
  xlab("dC13") + ylab("d15N")
p+ geom_text(data=subset(NescoA_sum, Class="Aves"),
          aes(x = d13C_mean, y = d15N_mean,label=Genus))
```

The data

```
structure(list(Class = c("Arachnida", "Arachnida", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Diplopoda", "Gastropoda", "Insecta", "Insecta", 
"Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", 
"Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", 
"Insecta", "Insecta", "Liliopsida", "Magnoliopsida", "Magnoliopsida", 
"Mammalia", "Mammalia", "Mammalia", "Mammalia"), Genus = c("(Lycosidae)", 
NA, "Catharus ", "Dumetella", "Empidonax", "Geothylpis", "Melospiza", 
"Passerina", "Pipilo", "Spizella", "Toxostoma", "Troglodytes", 
"Turdus", "Vireo ", "Cambala", "(Gastropoda)", "(Acrididae)", 
"(Scolytidae)", "Anasa", "Aphaenogaster", "Atlanticus", "Conocephalus", 
"Forficula", "Formica", "Melanolestes", "Melanoplus", "Metrioptera", 
"Myrmica", "Oulema", "Phyciodes", "Phyllopalpus", NA, "Andropogon", 
"Achillea", "Solidago", "Blarina", "Microtus", "Peromyscus", 
"Zapus"), d15N_mean = c(4.32, 5.235, 3.83, 5.068, 3.98666666666667, 
3.18, 5.22, 2.86, 4.39, 4.17, 4.84, 5.32, 3.44, 2.43, 2.31, 3.2, 
2.31, 2.46, 0.94, 4.16, 1.68, 1.32, -0.9, 7.22, 1.47, 0.26, 2.575, 
4.29, 0.32, 0.995, 2.435, 2.485, NA, 0.28, -1.54, 6.11, 4.30875, 
3.87666666666667, 4.13333333333333), d13C_mean = c(-25.07, -24.055, 
-24.92, -24.628, -23.9733333333333, -24.2, -24.8466666666667, 
-23.64, -25.28, -22.34, -24.21, -24.45, -24.285, -25.09, -19.95, 
-24.56, -27.94, -18.54, -26.18, -17.72, -24, -21.41, -24.75, 
-25.42, -25.81, -23.04, -27.265, -24.19, -21.935, -15.34, -19.865, 
-23.7664285714286, -11.915, -31.65, -30.55, -22.0733333333333, 
-22.98875, -22.81, -23.92), d15N_sd = c(NA, 1.46371103705615, 
NA, 0.939079336371534, 1.09367880720682, 0.74953318805774, 0.762692598626734, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.636396103067893, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.742462120245875, NA, 0.834386001800126, 
0.261629509039022, 0.912167747730646, 2.35327840060823, NA, NA, 
1.04651803615609, 1.25729869164014, 0.398405303320985, 1.60593690203984, 
0.849548899907082), d13C_sd = c(NA, 1.71826947828331, NA, 0.60363068179144, 
0.285014619508076, 0.127279220613578, 0.209841209807163, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.219203102167831, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0212132034355972, NA, 3.34461507501237, 
3.62038671967512, 0.51618795026618, 5.32832143743781, 0.0919238815542517, 
NA, 0.183847763108501, 3.12616911464069, 1.69705995769154, 0.523736575006939, 
0.444409720865778)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -39L), groups = structure(list(
    Class = c("Arachnida", "Aves", "Diplopoda", "Gastropoda", 
    "Insecta", "Liliopsida", "Magnoliopsida", "Mammalia"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:2, 3:14, 15L, 16L, 17:32, 33L, 34:35, 36:39), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: NescoA_sum not found?

Comment: Oh! NescoA_sum is the name of the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p + geom_text(aes(label = Genus), data = subset(df, Class == "Aves"), vjust = 1.5, hjust = 1.5)`

[image]